# Remove microseconds from Date and convert with toISOString()

Tags: javascript, date, real-time-updates

I try to subtract the milliseconds value of a `setInterval` from a Date object, but then i get an error with  `toISOString()`

```
 Uncaught TypeError: syncDate.toISOString is not a function
```

This is the code:

```
var syncDate = new Date();
syncDate=syncDate.setMinutes(syncDate.getSeconds() - obj.syncTimer / 1000)
syncDate=syncDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you mean milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: Look at what the return value of [`Date#setMinutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes) is. Checking documentation/reference material should **always** be your first step.

Comment: Ok. i cannot do it. can you help me with this?

Comment: *setMinutes* returns the new time value, a number, not a Date. So *syncDate* becomes a number which doesn't have a *toISOString* method. Just remove the assignment from `syncDate=syncDate.setMinutes(...)`.

Comment: Also, if *obj.syncTimer* is milliseconds, use *setMilliseconds*, not *setMinutes*.